# Combinatorics - Candy distribution in circles

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Hey this is the question

"You have a circle divided into 8 different pieces with candy distributed according to the image below. In one move you can add or remove one candy in each of two adjoining sectors. Can you with a certain amount of moves distribute the candy evenly across the circles?"

[image]

So my thoughts on this was that it would be rather simple, for the left circle you can easily see that because of the uneven number of "candies" already there it should be impossible by adding an even amount of candies to distribute them evenly. I'm however stuck on the right circle because I can't manage to distribute it evenly but I also can't explain why.

Comment: By "Distribute evenly", do you specifically mean one in each of the 8 pieces?

Comment: The same amount in all sectors, can be 1 (8 in total) or 2 (16 in total) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Alternately color the sectors black and white.

Comment: Okay I think I get it, is it because the two candies are each in the same color sector that would end up explaining to why this doesn't work? Because you can only add/remove 1 each to a pair of different colored sectors?